# Rating sum by joining two tables from range

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, backend

I have been trying to get the ratings of retail outlet score by joining with the table Survey.

The user will enter the rating of the survey through a mobile application and receive it in the database, =>

[image: Rating Table]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbvUl.png]

The Rated By is the User Id,
The Rate On is the date,
The Score ranges from -2 to 2
where -2 = Very Bad, -1 = Bad, 0 = Average, 1 = Good, 2 = Excellent

Now for the Survey Id, it's in a relationship with the Survey Table.

[image: Survey Table]

I inner joined both of the tables by their Survey Id's and selected only the retail outlet Id and the score from both the tables, as below

[image: Join of Rating & Survey Table]

But the problem is that when I add a new rating with some other user for the same retail outlet then it should add the both of them as I tried by various methods, but it shows as a separate record.

Comment: There is no need to post images as link since you can include any sample data as well formatted text.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I'm using sql server

Comment: But there is no rep limit for posting data as text. The big advantage there is others can use it. Images of data is not a good idea anyway. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) And what is the query you are using??

Comment: Ah! sorry I'm new to programming so i don't much understand correct format of asking a question

Comment: This is the query I'm using

Comment: select
Surveys.RetailOutletId, Ratings.Score from 
Ratings inner join Surveys  on ratings.SurveyId = Surveys.SurveyId

Comment: You may want to look into [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Sum score, group by RetailOutletId

Comment: Yes, Thank you i solved the problem.